# How to access Chromebook Android via ADB in local Linux VM?

Tags: android, linux, adb, chromebook

Backstory: I'm developing an app on a Chromebook using the Linux (Beta) feature whereby I have VS Code, GIT and everything else installed. Plugging my phone into the Chromebook pops up a "Connect to Linux" dialog which then makes it accessible via `adb` running in the Linux VM. From there I can install and run my test application as part of a build script. Parallel to this I have Android enabled on the Chromebook and set it into developer mode which lets me access `adb` via CROSH. From this shell I can install and run APK's directly on the Chromebook itself through its Android emulation layer.

What I would like to do (if it's even possible) is to **access the Chromebook's Android layer via `adb` in the local Linux (Beta) VM**. Thus I would be able to run my build script to run, install and launch on the Chromebook Android layer itself.

My idea: the Chromebook would need to provide an emulated USB device to the Linux VM *or* I could somehow setup the Chromebook Android stuff so that I could connect over a local port (TCP/IP) with adb.

Thoughts, insight, resources?

Comment: Have you seen/tried: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/9770692?hl=en

Comment: I hadn't seen that Support article but my Chrome OS (Version 87.0.4280.109) doesn't have this option even though I have both Linux (Beta), Google Play / Android, and Developer Mode successfully enabled. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Additional source of info: https://chromeos.dev/en/android-environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to run `adb connect arc` and then the Chromebook shows up in the ADB devices list!

Thanks to Morrison Chang who provided the link to https://chromeos.dev/ which led me to https://chromeos.dev/en/android-environment/deploying-apps#deploy-with-terminal .

It seems that if your Chromebook is in developer mode then the convenient UI "Develop Android apps" is not available.